# How to add two FAB in app one centerDocked in bottom nav and other at normal place

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

[image: exapmple Image]

I want to add two floating action buttons in an app but couldn't figure out how to manage this. Example UI is shown in the picture.

Comment: Two FABs are discouraged by the Material Design guidelines, regardless of how simple it is to do technically. :)  You'll run into issues with heroes too, I'm told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can achieve this by nesting two `Scaffold` widgets?

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: new BottomAppBar(
            shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
          body: Scaffold(
            floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.mail),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          )),
    ),
  );
}
```